# Transiting in the UK, going to US with valid visa

Tags: transit

I am a Swaziland Citizen travelling to the USA with a valid VISA to enter USA and will be transiting through Landon Heathrow to connect flight to USA, Do I need a transit visa ? If is important I am travelling on British Airways.

Comment: Please do not use an ALL-CAPS title.